# NSRegularExpression Pattern

Tags: ios, nsregularexpression

I am stuck defining that pattern that will produce the results I am looking for.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
NSError *regexError = nil;
NSRegularExpression *parsingRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(vector)\\((.*?)(?:,\\s*(.*?))*\\)"
                                            options:0
                                            error:&regexError];

NSString *mystring = @"vector(0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)";

NSTextCheckingResult *parse = [parsingRegex firstMatchInString:mystring
                                        options:0
                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];


NSLog(@"string0 =%@\n"[mystring substringWithRange:[parse rangeAtIndex:0]]);
NSLog(@"string1 =%@\n"[mystring substringWithRange:[parse rangeAtIndex:1]]);
NSLog(@"string2 =%@\n"[mystring substringWithRange:[parse rangeAtIndex:2]]);
NSLog(@"string3 =%@\n"[mystring substringWithRange:[parse rangeAtIndex:3]]);
NSLog(@"string4 =%@\n"[mystring substringWithRange:[parse rangeAtIndex:4]]);
NSLog(@"string4 =%@\n"[mystring substringWithRange:[parse rangeAtIndex:5]]);
```

I expect the following output:

```
string0 = vector(0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
string1 = vector
string2 = 0.1
string3 = 0.0
string4 = 0.0
string5 = 1.0
```

I Get the following output:

```
string0 = vector(0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
string1 = vector
string2 = 0.1
string3 = 1.0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSExtendedRegularExpressionCheckingResult rangeAtIndex:]: index 4 out of range'
```

Thank you

So this works:

The pattern is:

```
NSRegularExpression *parsingRegex = [NSRegularExpression 
                regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(vector)\\((.*?)(?:,\\s*(.*?))(?:,\\s*(.*?))(?:,\\s*(.*?))*\\)"
                options:0
                error:&regexError];
```

but only if the string is

```
NSString *mystring = @"vector(0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)";
```

If the String is:

```
NSString *mystring = @"value(0.1)";
```

I expected that:

```
NSRegularExpression *parsingRegex = [NSRegularExpression 
                regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(vector|value)\\((.*?)(?:,\\s*(.*?))(?:,\\s*(.*?))(?:,\\s*(.*?))*\\)"
                options:0
                error:&regexError];


NSLog(@"string0 =%@\n"[mystring substringWithRange:[parse rangeAtIndex:0]]);
NSLog(@"string1 =%@\n"[mystring substringWithRange:[parse rangeAtIndex:1]]);
NSLog(@"string2 =%@\n"[mystring substringWithRange:[parse rangeAtIndex:2]]);
```

would work and return

```
string0 = value(0.1)
string1 = value
string2 = 0.1
```

But it does not.

Any Ideas?

Comment: There are syntax- and copy/paste-errors in your NSLog statements.

Comment: copy and past errors corrected.  thx for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

`(vector)\((.*?)(?:,\s*(.*?))*\)` has 3 capture groups. It will never have have any more.

`(vector)\(([^,\s]+)\s*,\s*([^,\s]+)\s*,\s*([^,\s]+)\s*,\s*([^,\s]+)\s*,\s*([^)\s]+)\s*\)` is closer to what you want.